# qgis-web-client stuck on "Loading map" on some maps

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

Some maps work for me to load, while some of them never do.
They do load the layer names, but nothing more.
The javascript console in Chrome returns this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined WebgisInit.js:450postLoading WebgisInit.js:450Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode.listeners.load WebgisInit.js:236EXTUTIL.Event.fire ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:518EXTUTIL.Observable.fireEvent ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:159Ext.data.Node.Ext.extend.fireEvent ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:54140Ext.extend.loadComplete ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:55372(anonymous function) ext-base-debug.js:969Ext.extend.processResponse QGISExtensions.js:256Ext.extend.handleResponse ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:56415Ext.extend.handleResponse ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:6528handleTransactionResponse ext-base-debug.js:1887checkResponse ext-base-debug.js:1935(anonymous function) ext-base-debug.js:922
```

And if the project file (.qgs) contains a special character like åä or ö, it does not even load the layernames, and outputs this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined QGISExtensions.js:196Ext.extend.processResponse QGISExtensions.js:196Ext.extend.handleResponse ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:56415Ext.extend.handleResponse ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:6528handleTransactionResponse ext-base-debug.js:1887checkResponse ext-base-debug.js:1935(anonymous function) ext-base-debug.js:922
```

It does not matter if the shp-files themselves contain special characters, as I tried that on a working map without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.
I commented out line 445-466 in WebgisInit.js, and so far it seems to work.

Comment: Although the answer is short, the author did provide a solution to his own problem. Perhaps the author can edit his post and add a little more detail such as what was the line you commented out and does the solution completely fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code in your WebgisInit.js file where you get the 'width' error.

`var mapWidth = composerTemplate.map.width / ptTomm;`

This error is related to your print composer template. If this is the case, it looks like you have incorrect settings in your map print composer. Go to Composer Manager in QGis Application, check the width settings or delete your print composer if you don't need print composer.